# Force Windows 10 to always open hosts file with Notepad++

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, hosts-file

The Windows `hosts` file does not have an extension so Windows 10 by default does not allow creating a permanent association with a program.

How can I open the `hosts` file with Notepad++ without Windows asking which program to open the file with?

Comment: Short answer. You can't.

Comment: @DavidPostill No offense though thankfully you're not an all-knowing God. There is *always* a way, it just comes down to the right person seeing the question. ☺

Comment: I've been using Windows since version 2.0. Some things are just not possible. You need to accept that. **There is no built in mechanism in window to associate files with no extension to a specified program**. It is possible by writing a script but that doesn't allow double clicking on the file to open it. You might just as well right click and select Notepad++

Comment: @DavidPostill Edited the question, I think that is more accurate to describe what my end goal is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating fairly complex batch programs recently to open several programs (if they're not already open) I should have realized the answer:

```
C:\MEDIA\OFFICE\Notepad++\notepad++.exe C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer your question. "How do I **force** Windows 10 to always open the hosts file using Notepad++?" I can right click on hosts and open it with LiberKey or 7zip.

Comment: I realized I could create a shortcut to Notepad++ and have it automatically open a file so it negates having Windows constantly nag me about which program to open which is my goal. Is any of the wording confusing?

Comment: I know you can right click and select the editor. But actually associating a file (associations) that do not have an extension does not work on any system I have used

Answer (score 1):

You cannot associate files with no extension to be opened by a specific programs. Further, HOSTS needs to be opened with Notepad++ or Notepad or whatever editor in Admin mode.

So first you must get your editor in Admin mode. Then from there is is very easy to navigate to HOSTS and open it.

This is how I have done it for a very long time

Comment: Actually I just figured it out, thank you for your input nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in a batch file:

`start notepad "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\HOSTS"`

Optional: Then you could make a shortcut to that batch file, give it the same icon as the HOSTS file (on Windows 10 it's the first icon in shell32.dll) and you'd never know any different :)

If you want to use Notepad++ just change the path to that instead of Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can't have a direct association but you can place a shortcut to Notepad++ in your SendTo folder (shell:sendto) that gives you the option to open any file with Notepad++.
[image]

Comment: An interesting if albeit slightly more convoluted approach. My case is a single file instance so I created a shortcut to Notepad++ to open the file and it works perfectly. Your suggestion would be useful for a use case where more than a single file (or type or lack thereof?) is the major factor. Creative!

Comment: +1 but there is already an "Edit with Notepad++" shortcut ;).

Comment: I find that default shortcut a little "too prevalent" & remove it. I like send to for things like a hex editor, resource hacker, or anyting else you might want to use on a variety of files.